# Spark: How to capture column transition and groupby on the column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

| id | value | prevValue | indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | emp1 | null | 1 |
| 2 | emp2 | emp1 | 2 |
| 3 | emp1 | emp2 | 3 |
| 4 | emp1 | emp1 | 3 |
| 5 | emp3 | emp1 | 4 |
| 6 | emp3 | emp3 | 4 |
| 7 | emp1 | emp3 | 5 |
| 8 | emp2 | emp1 | 6 |
| 9 | emp2 | emp2 | 6 |
| 10 | emp2 | emp2 | 6 |

Lets say this whole set of rows is within one session window
I am have created the `prevValue` column using lag function
`lag("value", 1).over(sessionWindow).as("prevValue")`.

I wanted to create the indicator column like displayed in the table but haven't been successful yet.

There is a transition in value when value of prev row is not same as value of current row, whenever there is a transition the indicator row is incremented by 1 otherwise remains same as the previous row.

The main reasoning behind creating indicator column is to do a group by on indicators later.

Here what I was trying to do to create the column, but this doesn't work. Any help to resolve this would be appreciated.

```
.withColumn("indicator", when(col("prevValue").isNull, 1).otherwise(0))
.withColumn("indicator", 
  when(col("value") =!= col("prevValue"), lag("indicator", 1).over(sessionWindow) + 1)
  .otherwise(lag("indicator", 1, 1).over(sessionWindow)))
```

Comment: show clear input and output both, pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val indWindow = Window.orderBy("id")
val sumWIndow = Window.orderBy("id").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df.withColumn("changed", when(col("value") =!= lag(col("value"), 1).over(indWindow), 1).otherwise(0))
  .withColumn("group", sum("changed").over(sumWIndow))
```

produces:

```
+---+-----+-------+-----+
| id|value|changed|group|
+---+-----+-------+-----+
|  1|    a|      0|    0|
|  2|    a|      0|    0|
|  3|    b|      1|    1|
|  3|    c|      1|    2|
|  4|    c|      0|    2|
|  5|    c|      0|    2|
+---+-----+-------+-----+
```

**note**: This is a very performance inefficient solution as Spark will have to put all the rows in the same partition. Do you have any column to partition the data on?

Comment: if this is being taught as part of lessons, then we have some serious problems,

Comment: no this is not part of any lesson. emp is just place holder of actual value I can't provide.

Comment: thanks for this approach, I have found another solution using row_number function that also works and yes I am partitioning by a column not present here.